# Is Newton’s third law of motion formed from Poincare symmetries?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, symmetry, conservation-laws, poincare-symmetry, perpetual-motion

So I know that Newton's third law states that every action has an equal reaction, making a symmetry. But just like how Poincare symmetries form conservation laws, do any Poincare symmetries form Newton's third law?

(Side question: If not, what symmetry is Newton's third law based of?)

Answer (score 1):

The third law states that  momentum is conserved. From Noether we know that momentum consrevation is a consequence of translational symmetry. The tranlations are a subgroup of Poincare. So Yes.